# .htaccess if cookie does not exits, redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have `index.html` and `login.html` inside a folder `dev`, example: `http://www.example.com/dev/login.html`.

What I need is that everytime a user goes to `http://www.example.com/dev/index.html` or `http://www.example.com/dev/` for .htaccess to check if cookie **`login`** is equal too 1 to let user access otherwise redirect user to 
`http://www.example.com/dev/login.html`.

this is what i got so far, it works if user goes to http://www.example.com/dev/ but not if user enters http://www.example.com/dev/index.html it won't redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dev/$    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !login=2;?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dev/login.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: The reason for /dev/ working and /dev/index.html not working, is because of the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dev/$`

Comment: `^/dev/(?:index\.html)?$`